# UIButton with rounded corners using square setBackgroundImage

Tags: iphone, ios

So I create a button.  I want it to have rounded corners with out making rounded .png files 
I can set the background image ok.  I can round the corners ok.  However, when I set the background Image the rounded corners go away.

I did this once before a long time ago but can not seem to get it working again.  How can this be done?

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 addTarget:self action:@selector(goSpecials)
  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button1 setTitle:@"Specials" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.titleLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial-BoldMT" size:(15.0)];
[button1 setTitleColor:[self colorWithHexString:buttonColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage: [UIImage imageNamed: @"button.png"]]; 
 //[button1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(20.0, 232.0, 135.0, 32.0);
button1.layer.borderColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
button1.layer.borderWidth = 0.5f;
button1.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0f;
[self.view addSubview:button1];
```

button.png: 
[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add the maskToBounds property to your button.

```
button1.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```